# Just keep top/first line in wrapped text columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
project <- c("AAA", "BBB") 
note <- c("2/9 - Check in w/ Matt
           1/15 - Team Event
          1/12 - Kickoff",
          "Waiting for PO, 
          2/8 :: Sent PO")
df <- data.frame(project, note)
df

project     note
AAA         2/9 - Check in w/ Matt
            1/15 - Team Event
            1/12 - Kickoff
BBB         Waiting for PO
            2/8 :: Sent PO
```

I want to just select or keep the top line in the notes section.

Output:

```
project     note
AAA         2/9 - Check in w/ Matt
BBB         Waiting for PO
```

I imagine that I'll have to use RegEx and \n?

Comment: The provided data set doesn't look like you think it looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(df, 'note', sep='\n,', 'long')[,list(note=note[1L]) ,project]
 #   project                   note
 #1:     AAA 2/9 - Check in w/ Matt
 #2:     BBB         Waiting for PO
```